# path works from root only

Tags: php, path

I read through all I could find on the topic, but nothing worked for me. I run PHP 5.3.29.

I have this PHP code, that works from root, but not from folders:

```
  // Fetch latest poster
  $base_url = 'posters';
  $newest_mtime = 0;
  if ($handle = opendir($base_url)) {
  while (false !== ($latestFile = readdir($handle))) {
      if (($latestFile != '.') && ($latestFile != '..')) {
         $mtime = filemtime("$base_url/$latestFile");
         if ($mtime > $newest_mtime) {
            $newest_mtime = $mtime;
            $show_file = "$base_url/$latestFile";
         }
      }
    }
  }                  
  // Show latest poster
  $show_name = basename(trim($show_file, ".jpg"));
  echo '
  <a href="/' . $show_file . '">
  <img src="' . $show_file . '" class="jpg" width="150" alt="latest poster" title="' . $show_name . '">
  </a>';
```

I'd love to just add a slash to get root-relative paths, but that doesn't work in PHP.

This is the site with this issue:

http://flamencopeko.net (here there is no issue)

http://flamencopeko.net/disco_pages/sundays.php (this one has the issue)

Comment: `$base_url = getcwd() . '/posters';` ?

Comment: Thanks. This gave me http://home/flamenco/public_html/posters/08-05-2017_01.jpg too.

Comment: Which did not solve the problem.

Comment: It's because you're giving an absolute path for your `<img...` src. You need the web address which would be something like: `http://flamencopeko.net/postsers/ $YOUR_NEWEST_IMAGE` (*probably the `$latestFile`*).

Comment: Thanks for keeping the topic alive Darren. Highly appreciated. Yes, indeed. I'm painfully aware of this. 

$base_url = 'posters'; works from PHP files in root folder.

$base_url = '../posters'; works for PHP files in sub folder.

I need a solution that works from both locations.

I've read 20 articles and treads on the topic. Did not get a dot smarter.

Comment: [Here you go :-)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44937319/2518525)

Answer (score 2):

Change your $base_url to

```
$base_url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/posters';
```

To get root directory path of a PHP project:

For PHP >= 5.3.0

use: **DIR**

Note: The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.

For PHP < 5.3.0

use: dirname(**FILE**) or realpath(dirname(**FILE**))

Or in most common for getting server document root directory where projects resides :

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] or filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT')

Comment: Thanks. I do use include, or rather require, here yes. Like this: 

<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/left.php"); ?>

Using 

$base_url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/posters'; 

gave me: http://home/flamenco/public_html/posters/08-05-2017_01.jpg

I don't know how to format this comment. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I think where you want to start is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can only display the images on the root dir has nothing to do with your script. It has to do with the url's your placing in your `<img..` tag, like below;

**Root**

```
<img src='/posters/NAME_OF_IMG.jpg' ... />
```

<sup>*Which would resolve to something like: `http://www.yourwebsite.com/posters/NAME_OF_IMG.jpg`*</sup>

**Sub Dir**

<sup>*Which would resolve to something like: `http://www.yourwebsite.com/disco_pages/posters/NAME_OF_IMG.jpg` - WHICH DOESN't EXIST.*</sup>

What you need to do is modify your code to generate the `$show_file` url like this:

```
$base_url = getcwd() . 'posters';
$newest_mtime = 0;
if ($handle = opendir($base_url)) {
while (false !== ($latestFile = readdir($handle))) {
    if (($latestFile != '.') && ($latestFile != '..')) {
       $mtime = filemtime("$base_url/$latestFile");
       if ($mtime > $newest_mtime) {
            $newest_mtime = $mtime;
            $show_file = "http://www.yourdomain.com/posters/" . $latestFile;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>*Alternatively, you could use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead of `getcwd()` if required.*</sup>

This should work for you from every directory you attempt. You have to understand what your code is doing to understand why it isn't working as you want.

1. You're traversing through your directories at file level to find the newest file, correct? Hence you need the **absolute** path of the file to check these aspects.
2. You're providing that **absolute path** to the `<img ...` tag which won't work. Your website is expecting the relative path (`http://www.yourwebsite.com/posters/THE_IMAGE_NAME.jpg`).

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks again.

From root that resulted in:

Warning: opendir(/home/flamenco/public_htmlposters) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/flamenco/public_html/left_test.php on line 40

so I changed

```
base_url = getcwd() . 'posters';
```

to

```
base_url = getcwd() . '/posters';
```

This shows the poster, but it links to:

http://flamencopeko.net/http://flamencopeko.net/posters/08-05-2017_01.jpg

From sub-folder it results in:

Warning: opendir(/home/flamenco/public_html/disco_pages/posters) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/flamenco/public_html/disco_pages/left_test2.php on line 12

I was able to write a messy work-around, that works, just now:

```
$path = getcwd();
if ($path == '/home/flamenco/public_html') {
  $base_url = 'posters';
  $newest_mtime = 0;
  if ($handle = opendir($base_url)) {
  while (false !== ($latestFile = readdir($handle))) {
      if (($latestFile != '.') && ($latestFile != '..')) {
         $mtime = filemtime("$base_url/$latestFile");
         if ($mtime > $newest_mtime) {
            $newest_mtime = $mtime;
            $show_file = "$base_url/$latestFile";
         }
      }
    }
  }
  // Show latest poster
  $show_name = basename(trim($show_file, ".jpg"));
  echo '
  <a href="/' . $show_file . '">
  <img src="' . $show_file . '" class="jpg" width="150" alt="latest poster" title="' . $show_name . '">
  </a>';
  }
  else
  {
  $base_url = '../posters';
  $newest_mtime = 0;
  if ($handle = opendir($base_url)) {
  while (false !== ($latestFile = readdir($handle))) {
      if (($latestFile != '.') && ($latestFile != '..')) {
         $mtime = filemtime("$base_url/$latestFile");
         if ($mtime > $newest_mtime) {
            $newest_mtime = $mtime;
            $show_file = "$base_url/$latestFile";
         }
      }
    }
  }
  // Show latest poster
  $show_name = basename(trim($show_file, ".jpg"));
  echo '
  <a href="/' . $show_file . '">
  <img src="' . $show_file . '" class="jpg" width="150" alt="latest poster" title="' . $show_name . '">
  </a>';
  }
```